# how to specify the color for each plot in a subplot scenario with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code used to plot my data:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, subplot_titles=('futures', 'profit'), specs=[[{"secondary_y": False}], [{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=series1['timestamp'], y=series1['data']), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=series2['timestamp'], y=series2['data']), row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="USD", row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=profits['timestamp'], y=profits['balance']), secondary_y=False, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=events['timestamp'], y=events['s1_held']), secondary_y=True, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=events['timestamp'], y=events['s2_held']), secondary_y=True, row=2, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="USD", secondary_y=False, row=2, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Instruments", secondary_y=True, row=2, col=1)

fig.show()
```

How can I specify the color for each of the plots?
I've tried quite a variety of things, but no success so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the color of the lines, then you'll want to add either `marker_color = "css_color_here"` and/or `line_color = "css_color_here"` inside `go.Scatter()`.

Comment: is there a list of all the commands I can use inside Scatter?